# Is there a way to email pdf in codeigniter without phycial pdf file useing jsPDF

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my code i tried so far and im only getting blank pdf attachment.

```
var element = $("#html");
var getCanvas;

html2canvas(element, {
onrendered: function (canvas) {
getCanvas = canvas;
var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/,"data:application/octet-stream");
var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.addImage(imgageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
data = pdf
}
});
```

`data` I'm sending to email controller through `ajax` , to attach and send mail.

```
$buffer = $_POST['data'];
$this->email->attach($buffer, 'attachment', 'data.pdf', 'application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

Email attachment only takes file path and here there is no exact path exist .

You need the pdf file path to be included in email attachment so first save your generated pdf file to your server and than include that path in attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Email attachment only take path from the server and the path is not exist.you can create a pdf file and save to server by using tcpdf library for CI. You are using the client side pdf library to generate pdf.
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/TCPDF-Integration